# C#: Saving and Loading a list of ComboBox Items to/from the app.config file

Tags: c#, combobox, app-config

I am trying to save and load a list of combobox items to the .NET settings file (app.config).

With the following code, I want to load and save the data stored in an ArrayList *cboCollection*.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Settings.Default.cboCollection != null)
        this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(Settings.Default.cboCollection.ToArray());
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    ArrayList arraylist = new ArrayList(this.comboBox1.Items);
    Settings.Default.cboCollection = arraylist;
    Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

When I open the project’s Properties pages, and select the Settings tab, I would like to store {"myItem1","myItem2","myItem3"} in an ArrayList *cboCollection*. Unfortunately, there is no such type System.Collections.ArrayList to select. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You took this code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376622/c-how-do-you-save-a-list-of-items-like-a-combobox-to-the-net-settings-file) and asking why it doesn't work. Sorry dude, you should read that answer to understand what you are doing wrong, I'm not going to tell you that.

Comment: Yes, and I read it, but sorry I don't fully understand it. It says _If you do use an ArrayList, all of its elements' types must be serializable (have the [Serializable] attribute or implement System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable.)_. I added `using System.Runtime.Serialization`. Where do I need to have the [Serializable] attribute?

Comment: cboCollection is the name of the object that guy made out, you should implement yours and add [Serializable] on it.

Comment: I still don't get it. Where does cboCollection has to be implemented? In the constructor `Settings()` of class `Settings`? I thought that is the type in the *Settings Designer*.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you didn't do anything. You took this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376622/c-how-do-you-save-a-list-of-items-like-a-combobox-to-the-net-settings-file).

It doesn't work, because you didn't implement *cboCollection* object.

First you need a setting
[image]

then implement your class

```
[Serializable]
public MyClass
{
//something...
}
```

**EDIT:**
OK, forget about the class and just use System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection. This way you can add items to the settings.

```
System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection itemList = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
```

fill your combobox items into itemList by looping each of them.

and then you can do as follows:

```
Settings.Default.cboCollection = itemList;
```

Comment: What is `MyClass` supposed to do and where should it be implemented?

Comment: I know that I took this code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376622/c-how-do-you-save-a-list-of-items-like-a-combobox-to-the-net-settings-file), and I don't think there's anything wrong about that, as I never said that I did this myself. I still don't get your answer, as you don't really want to tell me one. Anyways, I found a solution [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/104121/combobox-problem.aspx), for those who will have the same problem.