# Can we restore multiple values from local settings(Application data)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1

I am working Windows phone 8.1 apps. In my project when user inputs text from textbox it should be displayed in listview. When user restarts the app the whole list items should be displayed. I tried in many ways but only one value is displayed in next app launch. Please help me

```
string ss = text_input.Text;
list_view.Items.Add(ss);
data.Values["add"] = ss;
```

Only one value is retrieved

```
if (data.Values["add"] != null)
      {
          list_view.Items.Add(data.Values["add"].ToString());
      }
```

All values should be displayed.

Comment: If I see correctly, your `data.Values["add"]` always refers to single value, doesn't it? So in code you posted, you are working single list item. What about the others?

Comment: Please help me how to add multiple items. Is it possible to restore multiple values. If so how..??

Comment: See this idea: [C#: How do you save a list of items like a Combobox to the .NET Settings file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/376622/2392157)

Comment: I am little bit confused by that example. Using foreach I think it can be done. But how to loop..                                                                                           `var ss = text_input.Text;
  list_view.Items.Add(ss);
  foreach (ListViewItem item in list_view.Items) 
            {
                data.Values["add"] = ss;
            }`

Answer (score 0):

You can join all of your values to one string. For example:

```
const string ITEMS_SEPERATOR = "#";
var values = string.Join(ITEMS_SEPERATOR, list_view.Items.Select(s => s.ToString() /*or whatever you want to save*/);
data.Values["add"] = values;
```

then when you want to restore yours settings:

```
forea(var item in data.Values["add"].Split(ITEMS_SEPERATOR))
{
list_view.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Note that it will fail if yours items contains '#'. So better way is using some serializator (binary or json or whatever). If there is a lof of items you should save it to file I think.